# ¿Cómo evitar insertar un registro dada cierta condición en MySQL?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sql-server

Tengo una base de datos para almacenar reserva de citas médicas, y lo que quiero saber es si es posible evitar la inserción de un registro si el día en el cual el usuario quiere la cita es Domingo, ya que ese día no se labora en el consultorio.

Para almacenar la reserva de citas tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE Cita
(
    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Fecha_Registro NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Fecha_Cita DATE NOT NULL,
    Hora TIME NOT NULL,
    Motivo NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Estado BOOLEAN NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
    Paciente_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Servicio_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)  
)
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

Y su relación:

```
CREATE TABLE ServicioDental
(
    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre_Servicio NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Duracion VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    Costo DECIMAL(6,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

Para obtener el día, tengo el siguiente query:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(Fecha_Cita) AS `Día`
FROM Cita
WHERE ID = 1002;
```

Si el día es Domingo, entonces que evite la inserción. Quizá sería menos complicado si tuviera una tabla para los horarios, pero como solo hay un doctor, no lo veo necesario.

Los datos se ingresarán mediante una aplicación en Android.

¿Me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Creo qué no necesitas conocer nada de la base de datos para hacer esto, sólo tendrás que comprobar que el día no sea domingo, programáticamente, antes de realizar el guardado de la cita.

Comment: Y si usas un CHECK comprobando que el dia fuera diferente a domingo, el chek lo crearias en la columna Fecha_Cita. por si no sabes que es un check. [aca explican](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

Comment: Men disculpame, no sabia que los CHECK en MYSQL, Son ignorados, el soporta su sintaxis por temas de compatibilidad, mas no los ejecuta como restrincciones

Comment: @andrezi:
No te apures, por eso no utilicé un CHECK, porque ya conocía que MySQL los acepta, mas no tienen efecto alguno.

Comment: @DanielSnv intentastes hacer una excepcion ejecutando un trigger

Answer (score 1):

Considero que enviar a la base de datos una consulta para que la bd la verifique por ti, aunque puedas hacerlo, es un error de concepción y puede afectar en mayor o menor grado el rendimiento de la app.

Supongamos que la BD está en un servidor remoto, o aunque no lo esté... sólo por lógica ¿por qué enviarle algo sin verificarlo antes? Sería gastar recursos inútilmente, por tanto mejor verificarlo en local y si no es domingo le pedimos a la BD que trabaje, mientras que cuando sea domingo (o festivo) no mandamos nada, controlando lo que se envía o no a nivel de la app.

Para saber si es domingo es muy fácil, puedes verificar el valor de  [`DAY_OF_WEEK`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) como sigue:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(tuFecha); //tuFecha es un objeto del tipo Fecha
int diaSemana = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
if (diaSemana==1){
    System.out.println ("¡Es Domingo!")
}else{
    System.out.println ("¡No es Domingo, a trabajar!")
}
```

Incluso, puedes impedir que el usuario seleccione una fecha que sea domingo deshabilitando los domingos. De acuerdo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40856644/5587982) no es posible con datepicker, pero se explica otra manera de hacerlo.

Y si quieres, iría más lejos, creando un calendario propio que muestre solamente los días laborables, pues como en todas partes, hay otros días que no son domingos en los que no se trabaja. ¿Por qué no tener un calendario a través del cual se controlen los días festivos en general, sean domingos o no, o los días en que el médico está de vacaciones?

Y... voy a ir más lejos todavía: ¿cómo controlas las horas? El médico no trabaja todo el día ¿no? ¿Por qué no tener un calendario controlado que de posibilidad de seleccionar citas solamente en los días y horas laborables?

Creo que un calendario de Google sería la mejor opción, [la API de Google](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) te ofrecería todas esas posibilidades y muchas más. Imaginemos que el médico necesita un reporte semanal de todas las citas y de los pacientes en esa cita. O que el paciente no tiene dispositivo móvil y necesita registrar la cita desde el sitio web. El calendario de Google lo puedes tener disponible también en línea...

Como ves, las posibilidades son enormes.

Comment: Agradezco mucho su respuesta, me ha sido de ayuda. Estoy comenzando en esto de la programación y bueno, me falla desarrollar mucho la habilidad. Gracias por compartirme estos puntos, prestaré más atención al momento de analizar los requerimientos.

Comment: Bueno y respecto a lo del horario, pasa que en ese consultorio solo labora ella, ya que es un consultorio dental (quizá omitir ese detalle cambiaría las cosas) pero por eso no vi necesario crear tabla para controlar los horarios, pero igual no sería malo hacerlo.

Comment: @DanielSnv aunque ahora haya solo un médico es posible que la situación cambie con el tiempo, que el consultorio crezca (eso esperamos :) ) y que haya más médicos. Si prevés eso desde ahora luego no tendrás que modificar la base de datos en producción. PD: No olvides marcar como solución la repuesta que haya resuelto o ayudado a resolver el problema, de modo que la pregunta no aparezca como sin solución. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes, crear un **SP**  Procedimientos Almacendos  desde  la base de datos y consumirlo por una web api,, o del lado del cliente en una cadena String y lo ejecutas ..

**Link de referencia.. con ejemplos**

https://www.codejobs.biz/es/blog/2014/07/09/como-hacer-un-procedimiento-almacenado-en-mysql-sin-morir-en-el-intento

**Aquí puedes obtener el nombre del día de la semana,, un ejemplo** 
http://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/MySQL/1431637-Como-saber-las-fechas-que-pertenecen-a-un-sabado-o-domingo.html

Comment: Ya sé trabajar con SP, es lo que estoy haciendo precisamente, en lo que ocupo ayuda es en saber cómo evitar un registro cuando el día seleccionado sea Domingo, o simplemente configurar el calendario e inhabilitar esos días. Pensaba también en una tarea asíncrona desde la app de Java, quizá, como ya me respondieron arriba, lo mejor sea desde la aplicación, solo que esperaba que alguien me ayudara a hacerlo con SQL.